# filtering out tr containing multiple css class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table and certain `tr` have a class **dblist_selected**. I want  to select the tr having the above mentioned class. I wrote a script like this

```
$("#tbodyDashBoard").find("tr[class='dblist_selected']")
```

and what this returns is `object[]`. The reason is the tr contains another class **selectable**
Then I modified the script like this

```
$("#tbodyDashBoard").find("tr[class='dblist_selected selectable']")
```

and this returns all the tr contains both the classes. All I need is to filter out and return the tr having the class **dblist_selected**. What should I do?

Comment: It returns `object[]` because `find` returns an object of matches elements and not because there is another class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the selector shown below :-

```
$("#tbodyDashBoard tr.dblist_selected")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `class selector` instead:

```
$("#tbodyDashBoard").find("tr.dblist_selected")
```

See [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
$("#tbodyDashBoard tr.dblist_selected:not(.selectable)")
```